# Create threads just once to use them n times later in C pthread

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

The problem is a square matrix multiplication, I was given the sequential script, where the matrices are loaded from a text file. The first line of the text file contains how many pairs of matrices are and their dimensions. So they are all the same size and stored by pairs. One by one all pairs should be multiplied and the result should be stored or printed in Terminal. So, I have to build a fine-grained version of the code, where the user decides to create **n** threads, and for each pair of matrices those **n** threads should take a portion of the job. The main problem is that my fine-grained version, in spite getting correct results, takes much more time than the sequential version to do the job, I reallized the problem was that I was creating and destroying threads for every pair of matrices, which I'm assuming takes a great ammount of time. So, is there a way to create those threads just once, and call them every time I need them?

Here is some part of the code:

```
for(k=0; k<nmats; k++) {//Loading matrices from matrices.data
printf("\nMatrix #%d of %d\n",k+1,nmats);
    for(i=0; i<matrixSize; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<matrixSize; j++) {
            fscanf(fh, "%lf", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<matrixSize; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<matrixSize; j++) {
            fscanf(fh, "%lf", &b[i][j]);
        }
    }

    //Creation of Threads
    for(t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++)
    {
        //The threads are created sequentially
        rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, mm, (void *)t);

        if (rc)
        {
            printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
for(t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++)
    {

        rc = pthread_join(threads[t], &status);
        if (rc)
        {
            printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
    printResult(fres,results);//Calling printing function
}
```

And the text file should look like this (1 pair of 3x3 size matrices for instance):

```
1 3
1 -5 20
0 3 4
-2 7 9
-2 4 -3
11 8 -4
6 9 5
```

Comment: A threadpool is probably what you want.

Comment: "which I'm assuming takes a great ammount of time." -- don't *ever* assume; measure! Otherwise you'll optimize the idle loop. http://wiki.c2.com/?OptimizingTheIdleLoop

Comment: Well, I assume it because I have measured time and it takes longer, it was just a matter of speaking, I'm not an expert.